# xrdp, usbip, разделение прав на проброшенные устройства

Tags: ubuntu, usb, udev, xrdp

День добрый. Есть терминальный сервер xrdp, на котором работает например 3 пользователя. Этим пользователям для работы нужен сканер штрихкода. Сканеры с удаленных машин пробрасываются на сервер xrdp через утилиту usbip. Как на сервере xrdp разделить эти сканеры между пользователями, чтоб программа, запущенная у каждого пользователя, понимала какой сканер из трех проброшенных ей нужно использовать? Разграничивать права через udev? Или может быть подскажите какой то другой способ решения?

Comment: обычно сканеры представляются как hid-устройства. т.е., как «ещё одна клавиатура». используемый вами rdp-клиент не перехватывает ввод от этого устройства (вслед за «основной» клавиатурой)?

Comment: remmina использую, нет не перехватывает. Сканер после проброса переводится в другой режим работы(нужный для 1С) с помощью баркода и всё. Сканер определяется как ttyUSB

Answer (score 0):

Пробрасывай как ком порт. На хосте со сканером ser2net вроде:

```
7000:telnet:0:/dev/ttyUSB0:115200 8DATABITS NONE 1STOPBIT
```

На хосте с 1C фоновый скрипт с socat:

```
while true
do
  socat pty,link=/dev/ttyUSB5 tcp:host1:7000 
done
```

Одинеска увидит как `USB COM6`.